# Tokenfield (tag input) autocomplete in Bootstrap 3 doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-tokenfield

I am trying to implement a simple tags input in Bootstrap 3 with Tokenfield, but I've stacked somewhere.

HTML code:

```
<link href="/static/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/static/css/bootstrap-tokenfield.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="form-group">
   <label for="myinput">Κατηγορία</label>
   <input id="myinput" type="text" class="form-control">
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
<script src="/static/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/bootstrap-tokenfield.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
   $('#myinput').tokenfield({
  autocomplete: {
    source: ['red','blue','green','yellow','violet','brown','purple','black','white'],
    delay: 100
  },
  showAutocompleteOnFocus: true
})
</script>
```

Error:
It doesn't show the autocomplete. I don't have any error in the console. I can add tags manually.

Comment: You don't need jQuery UI nor Typeahead Js if you don't need autocomplete feature. Just reduce the config object when initializing tokenfield.

Answer (score 3):

From what I see this it's the same problem I had a few days ago.
What you need as well is jquery-ui with autocomplete.js.

http://jqueryui.com/download/ generate your own jquery-ui.min.js including autocomplete.js and it should work.

Answer (score 3):

You do **NOT** necessarily need **jQuery UI**, nor **Typeahead Js**. If you are looking for

> a simple tags input

**without autocomplete** feature, just initialize like this

```
 $('#myinput').tokenfield();
```

Hope it helped.

Answer (score 2):

1. include jQuery UI (with autocomplete)
2. if you use "Bootstrap modal" or "jQuery-UI dialog" take a little fix:

```css
.ui-autocomplete { z-index: 5000; }
```

Answer (score 1):

The [**Tokenfield**](http://sliptree.github.io/bootstrap-tokenfield/#examples) works either with [Jquery Ui autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/download/) or with [Typeahead Js](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/). You must use one of them but from the code above you are not using any of them so of course nothing will happen. 
From the code above, you are trying to implement it with Jquery Ui autocomplete so you will need to link to the css and javascript of jquery Ui autocomplete

Read More about [**Bootstrap Tokenfield here**](http://sliptree.github.io/bootstrap-tokenfield/#examples)

Answer (score 0):

I know this answer came pretty late, but the autocomplete property for setting the lookup data is not `source` but `lookup`.

Tokenfield's example at http://sliptree.github.io/bootstrap-tokenfield/#options is not updated.

You can see that the right property is `lookup` from https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete

Answer (score 0):

It will work if you include both jquery-ui js and css.

- Go to this link [jquery-ui](https://jqueryui.com/download/all/)
- Download 1.12.0-rc.2 version of jquery
- Include both jquery-ui.css and jquery-us.js in your html

It worked for me.